# Extracting parts of a string with regular expression

Tags: regex, r

I've a bunch of strings that contains a pattern, which I want to extract.
It looks like the following:

```
  str <- "Regular Expression Language (AbcDfE-BB)"
```

So I would like two new columns, one with the "AbcDfE" part, and the other with the after - part, in this case "BB".

Comment: So... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the `(AbcDfE-BB)` part always at the end of the input?

Comment: `read.table(text = gsub('\\((.*)\\)|.', '\\1', str), sep = '-')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this for extracting these pieces: (It's a variation on the `parse.one` function from ?regexpr)

```
getMatchingPatterns <- function(data, pattern) {

   result <- gregexpr(pattern, data, perl = TRUE)
   do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(data), function(i) {
   if(any(result[[i]] == -1)) return("")
   st <- data.frame(attr(result[[i]], "capture.start"))
   le <- data.frame(attr(result[[i]], "capture.length") - 1)

   mapply(function(start,leng) substring(data[i], start, start + leng), st,  le)

}))
}
```

Then we define a perl style pattern where we name each variable, in this case (And this is a big assumption, based on one example),

`pattern <- "\\((?<ABCPart>.*?)-(?<BPart>.*?)\\)"`

so the first part I'm naming `ABCPart`, and the second one `Bpart`

then call the above function with that pattern:

```
> getMatchingPatterns(str,pattern)
      ABCPart  BPart
   [1,] "AbcDfE" "BB"
```

It returns it in a matrix form, which is easily convertible to data.frame, data.table etc...

The above function will find ALL matches for the given pattern, so beware how general your pattern is.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

https://regex101.com/r/oH1dV5/1

```
Regex
> ([a-zA-Z]*)-([a-zA-Z]*)

Data
>AbcDfE-BB
```

Answer (score 0):

You may remove what you do not need with `sub` and then `strsplit` with `-`:

```
str <- "Regular Expression Language (AbcDfE-BB)"
strsplit(sub(".*\\(([^()]+)\\).*", "\\1", str), "-", fixed=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/ek46Xq)

Here, `sub(".*\\(([^()]+)\\).*", "\\1", str)` will remove all text that is not the last `(...)` subtext (with the parentheses), and then will split with a literal hyphen character.

**Pattern details**:

- `.*`  - any 0+ characters as many as possible (greedy)
- `\\(` - a literal `(`
- `([^()]+)` - Group 1 that will be later accessed via `\\1` capturing 1 or more characters other than `(` and `)`
- `\\)` - a literal `)`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars up to the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would do:

```
strsplit(str,"(\\+)|\\-([a-zA-Z]+)")[[1]]
```